# Failed to query by spring-data-jpa query methods with suffix IN due to the cachedCriteriaQuery is not correct on openjpa 2.4.1

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin, spring-data-commons

**Update:**

After I digged into the source code of spring-data-jpa repository query methods, I found the root cause is the `createQuery` method of [PartTreeJpaQuery](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/c5ac2baa50b253b0fc5b11080aa159eeddbde3b5/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/PartTreeJpaQuery.java) as below.

This method will be called by the [invoke](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/01f2c30b1d1c342e168b3b541974332cc429e3e2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryFactorySupport.java#L438) method of the [QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/01f2c30b1d1c342e168b3b541974332cc429e3e2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryFactorySupport.java#L375) of the RepositoryFactorySupport when you call the spring-data-jpa repository query methods interface.

```
public Query createQuery(Object[] values) {

    CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery = cachedCriteriaQuery;
    List<ParameterMetadata<?>> expressions = this.expressions;
    ParametersParameterAccessor accessor = new ParametersParameterAccessor(parameters, values);

    if (cachedCriteriaQuery == null || accessor.hasBindableNullValue()) {
        JpaQueryCreator creator = createCreator(accessor, persistenceProvider);
        criteriaQuery = creator.createQuery(getDynamicSort(values));
        expressions = creator.getParameterExpressions();
    }

    TypedQuery<?> jpaQuery = createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    return restrictMaxResultsIfNecessary(invokeBinding(getBinder(values, expressions), jpaQuery));
}
```

At the first time call, the `cachedCriteriaQuery` variable will be `SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN (:deviceIdList) AND s.state IN (:states)) ORDER BY s.id` and the `values` variable is `[[1000000002], [5, 10]]` which are both correct as expected.

However, at the second time call, the `cachedCriteriaQuery` is **`SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id`** and the `values` is **`[[1000000003], [5]]`**. Looks like the value pass into openjpa and jpa query is correct but the `criteriaQuery` isn't.

If I changed the `openjpa` libs to version **2.2.2**, each time of calling this method, the `cachedCriteriaQuery` variable are **ALWAYS** `SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN (:deviceIdList) AND s.state IN (:states)) ORDER BY s.id`.

- Why the `cachedCriteriaQuery` variable will be changed?

  It is a [private and **final** field](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/c5ac2baa50b253b0fc5b11080aa159eeddbde3b5/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/PartTreeJpaQuery.java#L108) of QueryPreparer of PartTreeJpaQuery and the    only way can assign it shall be the [constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/c5ac2baa50b253b0fc5b11080aa159eeddbde3b5/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/PartTreeJpaQuery.java#L118) of QueryPreparer. I    have togged a breakpoint there, but between the first and second time    call, I haven't seen any process has called this constructor and how    can this variable became changed?
- All I have done is just changed the openjpa libs.

  But above codes are spring-data-jpa and/or spring-data-commons. How can this affect the behavior of the Query creation?

---

Give the unit test code as below to query the subtask entity by `find IN` the `deviceId` and `state` fields. The first time query is find IN deviceId `1000000002` and, state `5` and `10`. The second time query is find IN deviceId `1000000003` and state `5`.

```
List<Subtask> subtasks = this.subtaskDao.findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1000000002"}), Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{5, 10}));
System.out.println("1" + subtasks);
print(subtasks);
Thread.sleep(8000);
List<Subtask> subtasks1 = this.subtaskDao.findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1000000003"}), Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{5}));
System.out.println("2" + subtasks1);
print(subtasks1);

private void print(List<Subtask> subtasks)
{
    for (Subtask subtask : subtasks)
    {
        System.out.println(subtask.getId() + ", " + subtask.getDeviceId());
    }
}
```

The subtaskDao is `spring-data-jpa repository query method` interface as below

```
public interface SubtaskDao extends DaoBase<Subtask, Long>
{
    public List<Subtask> findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(@Param("deviceIdList") Collection<String> deviceIdList, @Param("states")  Collection<Integer> states);
}
```

However the results are as below which are not correct as we expect. The second time query has come out the result is the subtask of deviceId `1000000002` instead of deviceId `1000000003`.

According to the openjpa.Log, at the first time it query(at line 7272) `Query "SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN (:deviceIdList) AND s.state IN (:states)) ORDER BY s.id"`.
But at the second time, it query `Query "SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id"`. **Why the parameter are not `:deviceIdList` and `:states`?**

```
7248  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - Found datasource1: datasource 193492784 from configuration. StoreContext: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl@3344d163
7248  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl@21362712 created EntityManager org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@3344d163.
7272  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - Query "SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN (:deviceIdList) AND s.state IN (:states)) ORDER BY s.id" is cached."    
7273  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Query - Executing query: [Query: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl@5403907; candidate class: class devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask; query: null] with parameters: ?
7278  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.DataCache - Cache miss while looking up key "org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey@35db94c8[query:[SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id],access path:[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask],subs:true,ignoreChanges:false,startRange:0,endRange:9223372036854775807,timeout:-1]".
7317  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 2066366456, conn 178371348> executing prepstmnt 1924108520 
SELECT t0.id, t0.despair_count, t0.device_id, t0.domain_id, t0.finish_time, t0.remark, t0.state, t0.task_id, t0.task_type, t0.version 
    FROM subtask t0 
    WHERE (t0.device_id = ? AND t0.device_id IS NOT NULL AND (t0.state = ? OR t0.state = ?) AND t0.state IS NOT NULL) 
    ORDER BY t0.id ASC 
[params=?, ?, ?]
7324  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 2066366456, conn 178371348> [7 ms] spent
7357  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.DataCache - Put key "org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey@35db94c8[query:[SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id],access path:[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask],subs:true,ignoreChanges:false,startRange:0,endRange:9223372036854775807,timeout:-1]" into cache.
7358  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - <t 2066366456, conn 0> [0 ms] close
7360  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - Query "SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN (:deviceIdList) AND s.state IN (:states)) ORDER BY s.id" is removed from cache  excluded permanently. Query "SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN (:deviceIdList) AND s.state IN (:states)) ORDER BY s.id" is not cached because its result is not obtained by executing a select statement. This can happen if the query was evaluated in-memory. The result was provided by org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryCacheStoreQuery$CachingResultObjectProvider.  .
7361  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@3344d163.close() invoked.
1[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@16f15ae9, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@6206b4a7, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@77896335]
981, 1000000002
982, 1000000002
983, 1000000002
15371  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - Found datasource1: datasource 193492784 from configuration. StoreContext: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl@5d14e99e
15371  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl@21362712 created EntityManager org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@5d14e99e.
15372  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - Query "SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id" is cached."   
15372  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Query - Executing query: [Query: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl@38cfecf3; candidate class: class devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask; query: null] with parameters: ?
15372  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.DataCache - Cache miss while looking up key "org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey@35db9909[query:[SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id],access path:[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask],subs:true,ignoreChanges:false,startRange:0,endRange:9223372036854775807,timeout:-1]".
15373  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 2066366456, conn 178371348> executing prepstmnt 632104437 
SELECT t0.id, t0.despair_count, t0.device_id, t0.domain_id, t0.finish_time, t0.remark, t0.state, t0.task_id, t0.task_type, t0.version 
    FROM subtask t0 
    WHERE (t0.device_id = ? AND t0.device_id IS NOT NULL AND (t0.state = ? OR t0.state = ?) AND t0.state IS NOT NULL) 
    ORDER BY t0.id ASC 
[params=?, ?, ?]
15374  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 2066366456, conn 178371348> [1 ms] spent
15375  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.DataCache - Put key "org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey@35db9909[query:[SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id],access path:[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask],subs:true,ignoreChanges:false,startRange:0,endRange:9223372036854775807,timeout:-1]" into cache.
15375  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - <t 2066366456, conn 0> [0 ms] close
15375  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - Query "SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id" is removed from cache  excluded permanently. Query "SELECT s FROM Subtask s WHERE (s.deviceId IN ('1000000002') AND s.state IN (5,10)) ORDER BY s.id" is not cached because its result is not obtained by executing a select statement. This can happen if the query was evaluated in-memory. The result was provided by org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryCacheStoreQuery$CachingResultObjectProvider.  .
15375  PersistenceUnitAppDeploy  TRACE  [main] openjpa.Runtime - org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@5d14e99e.close() invoked.
2[devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@1860a7a1, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@40d96578, devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask@c97721b]
981, 1000000002
982, 1000000002
983, 1000000002
```

The version of `spring`, `spring-data-jpa`, `jdbc driver` and `openjpa` libs we used as follows, and the jdk is `1.8`, the database is `PostgreSQL 9.4 windows version`.

```
<springVersion>4.3.0.RELEASE</springVersion>
<springDataJpaVersion>1.10.2.RELEASE</springDataJpaVersion>
<openjpaVersion>2.4.1</openjpaVersion>
<postgreSQLJDBCVersion>9.4.1208</postgreSQLJDBCVersion>
```

The entity classes are enhanced at the build time by `openjpa-maven-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${openjpaVersion}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enhancer</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>${openjpaVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <includes>devicemanage/repository/**/*.class</includes>
        <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
        <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `EntityManagerFactoryBean` settings and `persistence.xml` are as below

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PersistenceUnitAppDeploy" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
          <prop key="openjpa.ConnectionURL">jdbc:postgresql:127.0.0.1:5432/database</prop>
          <prop key="openjpa.ConnectionUserName">user</prop>
          <prop key="openjpa.ConnectionPassword">user</prop>
          <prop key="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitAppDeploy" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>devicemanage.repository.appdeploy.entity.Subtask</class>
        ... // ommit other entity declaration
        <properties>

            <property name="openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider" value="sjvm" />
            <property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
            <property name="openjpa.InverseManager" value="true(Action=warn)" />

            <property name="openjpa.OrphanedKeyAction" value="log(Channel=Orphans, Level=TRACE)" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=200" />
            <property name="openjpa.Multithreaded" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.LockManager" value="none" />
            <property name="openjpa.WriteLockLevel" value="none" />

            <property name="openjpa.Compatibility" value="QuotedNumbersInQueries=true" />

            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Runtime=TRACE, Tool=TRACE, SQL=TRACE, Query=TRACE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Even if I have set both the **QueryCache** and **QuerySQLCache** to **false**, it still not works right.

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="false" />
<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="false" />
```

However, if I downgrade the `openjpa` libs to version `2.2.2`, **it works well exactly with all the same code and configuration**. Moreover, if I used the `@Query` for the subtaskDao interface as below, it also works well even with `openjpa version 2.4.1`.

```
@Query("SELECT entity FROM Subtask as entity WHERE entity.deviceId IN :deviceIdList AND entity.state IN :states")
public List<Subtask> findByDeviceIdInAndStateInOrderByIdAsc(@Param("deviceIdList") Collection<String> deviceIdList, @Param("states")  Collection<Integer> states);
```

What is the tricky I haven't discover?